# Consecutive reads of slave device - Best solution?

Tags: c

I would like to perform 5 consecutive reads to a slave devices and check if
those 5 read results are all equal. If not the w1_read_state function should be called
again till all the 5 read results are equal. What is the best solution? I started with some code like this...

```
static w1_slave slave;
static int tmp[5];
unsigned int i;

for (i=0; i < sizeof tmp / sizeof char; i++)
    w1_read_state(&slave, &tmp[i]);
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int last, consecutive;
w1_read_state(&slave, &last);
consecutive = 1;
while (consecutive < 5) {
    int tmp;
    w1_read_state(&slave, &tmp);
    if (tmp==last) {
        consecutive++;
    } else {
        last = tmp;
        consecutive = 1;
    }
}
```